# How to keep a thread alive and waiting for a boolean?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, loops, unity-game-engine

I have a thread in a unity(c#) application and this thread's duty is to wait for a boolean to become true and then save something and die. since I mentioned unity, I want to also say that the class that contains my codes is not a `MonoBehaviour` hence I do not have the `Update()` to repeatedly check for the boolean.

I tried to make a `MonoBehaviour` class and use its `Update()` to do the job but the properties of the Non-MonoBehaviour class (the main class) are all private and can not be accessed from other classes.

The simplest and cleanest way I found to do that is, to have a while loop in the thread to keep it alive. Since the while loop was drawing a lot of CPU power I added a `Thread.Sleep(500)` inside of it which apparently fixed the problem according to the task manager.

My question is, Is having a while loop inside of a thread in order to keep it alive a good practice? and also about the `Thread.Sleep(500)`, is it OK to slow down a loop using `Thread.Sleep(500)`

Here is my code:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(500);


            if (!_isRunning)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (RequiredSegments < minSegments)
            {
                continue;
            }

            IsDone = _object.SaveSegments();

            if (IsDone)
            {
                FetchValues();
            }

            Terminate();

            break;
        }
    });

    thread.Start();
```

Please feel free to give me any suggestion,

Regards

Comment: Have you considered using Coroutines?

Comment: Not familiar with Unity, but there are tons of synchronization primitives available in .net. Take your pick. `AutoResetEvent`, `ManualResetEvent`, `Semaphore`, `Mutex` (and their `Slim` versions), etc.

Comment: Use [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events) .. there is no need to poll check a flag ..

Comment: Spinning up a thread just to check for a bool is a waste of a perfectly good thread `Sleep` or otherwise

Comment: This is a hacky solution to see when you've saved some data elsewhere. Show us this elsewhere code and maybe we can fix that for you. This hack is just simply not the way to go.

Comment: @Daniel Corountines can only be used in Monobehaviour, and as i mentioned, this class is not. thanks

Comment: @Enigmativity my elsewhere code is just a `File.WriteAllText()` that writes some floats to a text file. Thanks

Comment: Why not making this class a MonoBehaviour then? And if this isn't an option, whats wrong with `while(true){ if(condition) break; Thread.Sleep(1); }`? I don't see anything wrong with that. If you don't want to use `Sleep`, you don't need to, since an eternal loop in a thread theoretically shouldn't stop your game's main thread from running.

Comment: @MushroomTip - Why not directly call `File.WriteAllLinesAsync` and wait for that to finish?

Comment: Dear @Daniel that's actually my question, I was asking if it is a good practice to keep a thread alive like that